# SVG view using Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, svg

I am using SVG based graph-node display in PhoneGap 2.1. The issue is i have not been able to resize the SVG canvas as the graph overflows out of the screen and no scroller is activated as the html page itself remains same sized. I have to make the SVG canvas fully scrollable/draggable within the HTML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look at you meta tags, the "viewport" could help you :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: yes i have used the meta tag already and it is not helping either.